# java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'lower_case_table_names' из-за чего?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Изучаю *JDBC* *MySQL*.

Создал соединение. При подключении выдает исключение:

`java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'lower_case_table_names'`.

Добавил в `my.ini` строку `lower_case_table_names = 1`, перезапустил сервер, но все тщетно! Кто знает, помогите, пожалуйста. В чем проблема?

Код программы:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Чивапчичи
 */
public class A {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static final String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rsreu";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String password = "";

    // JDBC variables for opening and managing connection
    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stmt;
    private static ResultSet rs;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            // opening database connection to MySQL server
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);

            // getting Statement object to execute query
            stmt = con.createStatement();


        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //close connection ,stmt and resultset here
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                /*can't do anything */ }
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                /*can't do anything */ }
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                /*can't do anything */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Из командной строки к базе подключается? Если подключается, то введи команду: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "lower_case_table_names"; Что пишет?

Comment: @Владимир  
mysql>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  
"lower_case_table_names";  
+------------------------+-------+  
| Variable_name          | Value |  
+------------------------+-------+  
| lower_case_table_names | 1     |  
+------------------------+-------+  
1 row in set (0.14 sec)

Comment: А какую версию connetion'a Вы используете? Похоже, что Вы используете какую-то старую версию MySQL, но драйвер уже нового поколения. Я бы попробовал сделать downgrade версии mysql-connector-java-*.jar, а лучше найти информацию о том какая версия официально поддерживается для Вашей версии DB сервера.
Так или иначе сбрасывайте версию MySQL и драйвера, который используете - причина где-то там.
Кстати, я взял ваш код и на моем MySQL 5.7.19 все заработало с mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar

Comment: 6.0.6 альфа версия mysql. Наверное, баг)

Comment: Да, верно! Альфа версия 6.0.6 оказалась с багом. Проблема решена переходом на более старую версию 5.5.23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал 6.0.6 альфа версию mysql. Как оказалось, проблема в самой СУБД. Перешел на более старую версию. Все работает!